# Why isn't this default DataTemplate, for my view model, getting picked up?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I declared a `ViewModel`:

```
public class DefaultViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    public DefaultViewModel()
    {
        this.DisplayName = "Welcome!";
    }
}
```

and I leverage the `CollectionViewSource` to set my active "workspace":

```
// this code comes from the MainWindowViewModel.cs
void SetActiveWorkspace(WorkspaceViewModel workspace)
{
    Debug.Assert(this.Workspaces.Contains(workspace));

    ICollectionView collectionView =
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Workspaces);
    if (collectionView != null)
        collectionView.MoveCurrentTo(workspace);
}
```

and in the constructor of the `MainWindowViewModel.cs` I setup a default "workspace":

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    this.DisplayName = "Big File Reader";

    var viewModel = new DefaultViewModel();
    this.Workspaces.Add(viewModel);
    this.SetActiveWorkspace(viewModel);
}
```

All should be well at this point. Now, I want to display each "workspace" in a new tab, so I marked up my `TabControl` and synchronized it:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        Margin="4">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel Width="120">
                            <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
                                    Content="X"
                                    Cursor="Hand"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    Focusable="False"
                                    FontFamily="Courier"
                                    FontSize="10"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Margin="0,1,0,0"
                                    Padding="4"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource
                                        ResourceKey={
                                            x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Then, in an external resources file I defined the default view for the view model:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:BigFileReader"
                    xmlns:lv="clr-namespace:BigFileReader.Views">
    <DataTemplate DataType="l:DefaultViewModel">
        <lv:DefaultView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and I included that resource dictionary in my main window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
```

*Now, the header displays fine for each `TabItem`. It displays the `DisplayName` as expected.*

**But, the `ContentTemplate` for the `TabItem` isn't picking up the default view, it just displays a `TextBlock` with the `ToString()` of the `DefaultViewModel`, which of course is the full name of the type.**

Why isn't the default template being picked up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="l:DefaultViewModel">
    <lv:DefaultView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

to this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:DefaultViewModel}">
    <lv:DefaultView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

It happened to me once. I was struggling with it for like 1 hour, only to discover this simple solution. Try it out.